# Intel x64 c++ inline assembly in vs 2015

Tags: inline, inline-assembly

I use `rsp` and `rbp` registers for memory indexing in x64 inline assembly with VS 2015 C++. Is it possible without save and restore `push rsp, push rbp`,... pop rbp, pop rsp?

```
__asm{

mov rsi, memory
mov rsp, rsi
mov rbp, rsi
...
movntps [rsp+rdx], ymm0
... 

}
```

In debugging mode, after `mov rbp, rsi`, the base address of memory is changed. Is this no problem?

Comment: I don't see how this code could have compiled under vs2015.  This is 64bit code (since your register names start with 'r'), which vs2015 does not support using inline asm.  Perhaps you meant `esi`, `esp`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

When writing inline assembly, you must conform to the compiler's rules for what registers you are allowed to use.  [VS2015's rules are documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a8ss06.aspx) and I will quote the key bit:

> When using `__asm` to write assembly language in C/C++ functions, you don't need to preserve the EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, or EDI registers...You should preserve other registers you use (such as DS, SS, SP, BP, and flags registers) for the scope of the `__asm` block.

Read "should" as "must".  So the narrow answer to your question is "No, you must save and restore ESP and EBP if you want to use them for anything."

Reading between the lines, I think what you actually want is to write your entire function in assembly language.  With Visual Studio, that means you will put it in a separate `.ASM` file.  You still have to conform to the [*calling convention*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl), but not the compiler's stricter rules for `__asm` blocks.  Note that the calling convention still requires you to save and restore ESP and EBP (and, in fact, all registers except EAX, ECX, and EDX).

If you are actually coding for x64/Windows, then, if I'm reading this documentation correctly, you *can't* use `__asm`; you must use a separate `.ASM` file.  And the calling convention is different.